# pandas - checking a condition for each group in a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have got a dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'index' : range(8),
'variable1' : ["A","A","B","B","A","B","B","A"],
'variable2' : ["a","b","a","b","a","b","a","b"],
'variable3' : ["x","x","x","y","y","y","x","y"],
'result': [1,0,0,1,1,0,0,1]})

df2 = df.pivot_table(values='result',rows='index',cols=['variable1','variable2','variable3'])
df2['A']['a']['x'][4] = 1
df2['B']['a']['x'][3] = 1

variable1   A               B    
variable2   a       b       a   b
variable3   x   y   x   y   x   y
index                            
0           1 NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
1         NaN NaN   0 NaN NaN NaN
2         NaN NaN NaN NaN   0 NaN
3         NaN NaN NaN NaN   1   1
4           1   1 NaN NaN NaN NaN
5         NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN   0
6         NaN NaN NaN NaN   0 NaN
7         NaN NaN NaN   1 NaN NaN
```

Now I want to check for simultaneous occurrences of `x == 1` and `y == 1`, but only within each subgroup, defined by `variable1` and `variable2`. So, for the dataframe shown above, the condition is met for `index == 4` (group `A-a`), but not for `index == 3` (groups `B-a` and `B-b`).

I suppose some `groupby()` magic would be needed, but I cannot find the right way. I have also tried experimenting with a stacked dataframe (using `df.stack()`), but this did not get me any closer...

Comment: you are chain assigning, which works in this case, but see [here](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/indexing.html#indexing-view-versus-copy), better to do ``df2.loc[:,('A','a','x',4)] = 1``

Answer (score 1):

You can use `groupby` on the 2 first levels `variable1` and `variable2` to get the sum of the `x` and `y` columns at that level:

```
r = df2.groupby(level=[0,1], axis=1).sum()

r
Out[50]: 
variable1   A       B    
variable2   a   b   a   b
index                    
0           1 NaN NaN NaN
1         NaN   0 NaN NaN
2         NaN NaN   0 NaN
3         NaN NaN   1   1
4           2 NaN NaN NaN
5         NaN NaN NaN   0
6         NaN NaN   0 NaN
7         NaN   1 NaN NaN
```

Consequently, the lines you are searching for are the ones that contain the value 2:

```
r[r==2].dropna(how='all')
Out[53]: 
variable1  A       B    
variable2  a   b   a   b
index                   
4          2 NaN NaN NaN
```

Comment: That looks good, but what can I do when searching for a more generic solution? For example when I have `variable3 == x || y || z`? I know I could do some magic with numbers (e.g. `x -> 1`, `y -> 2`, `z -> 4`, so that every combination of sums is unique, but this gets complicated...)